# Getting "already seen ipaddr" error when adding 2 secondary IPv6 addresses on a VLAN subinterface

Tags: linux, centos, ip, ipv6, centos-7

How many secondary IPv6 addresses are allowed on a VLAN subinterface in CentOS 7? With the config below I only get the former IPv6 address successfully assiged to ens224.2015 while the latter IPv6 address assignment fails with "network: ERROR     : [/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-aliases] error in ifcfg-ens224.2015:2: already seen ipaddr  in ifcfg-ens224.2015:1". Is that because I'm trying to allocate them from the same /64 subnet?

Many thanks in advance!

```
[root@tools-centos7 network-scripts]# cat ifcfg-ens224.2015:1
DEVICE=ens224.2015:1
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="no"
IPV6ADDR=240b:c0d0:101:27df::1:229/64
PEERDNS=no
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
VLAN=yes
[root@tools-centos7 network-scripts]#
[root@tools-centos7 network-scripts]#
[root@tools-centos7 network-scripts]# cat ifcfg-ens224.2015:2
DEVICE=ens224.2015:2
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="no"
IPV6ADDR=240b:c0d0:101:27df::2:229/64
PEERDNS=no
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
VLAN=yes
[root@tools-centos7 network-scripts]#
```

Comment: I recommend you not use alias interfaces. Linux supports multiple IP (v4 and v6) addresses on the same interface natively.

Comment: Daniel B: Thank you - any chance to share the recommended syntax for that?

Comment: I’m not familiar with CentOS, sorry. You’ll have to find out how that works with the CentOS network configuration method, if at all.

Comment: Daniel B: I've just digged it out and posted as an answer - thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

Following Daniel B's hint I got it working by means of adding IPV6ADDR_SECONDARIES with them into ens224.2015 itself alongside IPV6ADDR (instead of using ens224.2015:1 and ens224.2015:2):

```
[root@tools-centos7 network-scripts]# cat ifcfg-ens224.2015
DEVICE=ens224.2015
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="no"
IPV6ADDR=240b:c0d0:101:27df::229/64
IPV6ADDR_SECONDARIES="240b:c0d0:101:27df::1:229/64 240b:c0d0:101:27df::2:229/64"
PEERDNS=no
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
VLAN=yes
[root@tools-centos7 network-scripts]#
[root@tools-centos7 network-scripts]# service network restart
Restarting network (via systemctl):                        [  OK  ]
[root@tools-centos7 network-scripts]#
[root@tools-centos7 network-scripts]# ifconfig ens224.2015 | grep 229
        inet6 240b:c0d0:101:27df::229  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 240b:c0d0:101:27df::1:229  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 240b:c0d0:101:27df::2:229  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
[root@tools-centos7 network-scripts]#
```